# Who were the members of the last High Council of System Lords?

Tags: stargate, stargate-sg1, goauld

In [Reckoning, Part 1](http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Reckoning,_Part_1_(episode)) we meet [the High Council of System Lords](http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/High_Council_of_System_Lords) for the last time, as they are eliminated by the Replicators.

At this point in time the Council consists of [Yu](http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Yu) (in the middle) and two unknown Goa'uld:
[image: High Council of System Lords]

Who were those two Goa'uld?

Comment: I tried watching the scene, credits, imdb all again but I cant find any information about them. They are just throwaway characters. I think that was the point. At this point the System Lords are so beaten that there is only one we know and two (likely) minor Lords that Yu has allied with to keep some semblance of a council intact.

Answer (score 8):

The High Lords that were at the council were Lord Yu (insert joke here), Ba'al, [Svarog](http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Svarog), [Olokun](http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Olokun), [Kali](http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Kali), [Bastet](http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Bastet) and [Morrigan](http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Morrigan) as well as [Osiris](http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Osiris), representing Anubis.

[image]

In addition to the High Lords are a host of *lesser System Lords*. The two Goa'uld that you've pictured don't appear to be named in the script nor the official cast/crew listings. They're just 'unnamed extras' brought in as set furniture.

There are no end of minor lordlings that these two could be including Afa and Vritra, mentioned earlier in the show but never *actually* seen.